# Combining two/four tables

Tags: sql, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, bigdata, rdd

I am working on a spark programm that essentially is trying to combine following two tables:

Table1

---

```
+---+---+---+  
| a | b | c |  
+---+---+---+  
| 1 | 2 | 6 |  
| 4 | 5 | 6 |  
+---+---+---+
```

---

Table2:

---

```
+---------+-----+--------+  
|Attribute|Value|Validity|  
+---------+-----+--------+  
|    A    |  1  |  false |  
|    A    |  4  |  false |  
|    B    |  2  |  false |  
|    B    |  5  |  false |  
|    C    |  6  |  true  |  
+---------+-----+--------+
```

---

I want to look up for each (attribute,value) pair if it is valid. 
Basically a resulting table table that contains all information I need could look like this:

```
+-+-+-+---------+---------+---------+  
|A|B|C|ValidityA|ValidityB|ValidityC|  
+-+-+-+---------+---------+---------+  
|1|2|6|  false  |  false  |  true   |  
|4|5|6|  false  |  false  |  true   |  
+-+-+-+---------+---------+---------+
```

Above table would be possible by for example triple joining after doing some preprocessing on the tables. But a triple join seems very inefficent for me, since I am working with bigdata.
Also I would have to use a loop to perform each join seperatly, which I also do not want.

Does anybody know a way to archive above result with a single query (additional preprocessing and easy changes to the tables is no problem)?

I cant get the formating to work properly, sry about that.

kind regards
-Barry

Comment: You could transpose table1 and perform a single join with pivot.

Answer (score 1):

You can `join` the tables, once for each attribute:

```
select t1.*,
       a.validity as validityA,
       b.validity as validityB,
       c.validity as validityC
from table1 t1 left join
     table2 a
     on t1.a = a.value and a.attribute = 'A' left join
     table2 b
     on t1.b = b.value and b.attribute = 'B' left join
     table2 c
     on t1.b = c.value and c.attribute = 'C';
```

Note:  This returns `NULL` validity column values when there is no match in `table2`.

Comment: As written in the question I was hoping for a different way, mlre efficient way, since I am working with big data

Comment: @Barry . . . This is probably fine from a performance perspective.  And although I see a reference to an approach in your question, I don't see a query, so I really can't say that this has anything to do with what you might have tried.